# EF TPH - can I use a boolean column as a discriminator?

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance

I am using Entity Framework.
Is it possible to use a boolean column as a discriminator column in Table Per Hierarchy (TPH) scenario?
I do not control the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Assume you have discriminator column named `EntityType`:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<ParentEntity>()
     .Map<DerivedA>(m => m.Requires("EntityType").HasValue(true))
     .Map<DerivedB>(m => m.Requires("EntityType").HasValue(false));
```

That requires discriminator column to be of type `(bit, null)`

Comment: @MaximEliseev just add *IsRequired* to these mappings, e.g. `m.Requires("EntityType").HasValue(true).IsRequired()`